# Python: Convert Tuple hex strings into integer

Tags: python, type-conversion, hex

I need to convert some tuple in *little endian* hex format into *integer* format, how do i do so?

Example:

```
myTuple = ['0xD4', '0x51', '0x1', '0x0']
```

I need to convert it into `integer` (`86484`).

Comment: how do you expect the sequence of hex values `['0xD4', '0x51', '0x1', '0x0']` to become a single `86484`?

Comment: By the way [] is list, not tuple.

Answer (score 5):

Just convert your `hex_string` into `int` with `int(hex_string, 16)` and use `struct` lib to merge 4 bytes into one `big int`:

```
import struct

myTuple = ['0xD4', '0x51', '0x1', '0x0']

myResult = struct.unpack("<I", bytearray((int(x, 16) for x in myTuple)))

print(myResult[0])
```

`<` is the endianess, `I` is big int (4 bytes)

Answer (score 2):

On python2 , using `int.frombytes`

```
int.from_bytes(bytearray((int(x, 16) for x in myTuple)), byteorder='little')
# 86484
```

Or explicitly summing up each value after shifting it

```
sum(int(e, 16) << (i * 8) for i,e in enumerate(myTuple))
# 86484
```

Or using `reduce`

```
from functools import reduce    # only for python3
reduce(lambda x, y: (x<<8) + int(y,16), [0]+myTuple[::-1])
# 86484
```

Comment: `int.frombytes` Works if he's using Python3

Comment: Well... OP hasn't mentioned he is using python3. But a fair point. I will add a note

Comment: I have tried:
int.from_bytes(bytearray((int(x, 16) for x in myTuple)), byteorder='little')
and it works! Thanks!!